# Spring boot/Cloud Eureka DiscoveryClient - No such host is known

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I want to try out microservices using 2.5.4 spring boot and getting problems in discovery

Steps:

Created a RestTemplate with @LoadBalanced, and trying to call the service using "application name in the url"

I have the register and fetch registry true in properties (thought this should get available services?)

> Error: No such host is known

I am trying

```
@Autowired
private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;
```

and do

```
 discoveryClient.getInstances("myappservice-name").forEach((ServiceInstance s) -> {
            System.out.println(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(s));
        });
```

But all examples tell to use an endpoint? or commandLineRunner. Both I'm looking for auto loading

https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/

https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/microservice-registration-and-discovery-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-s-eureka

Not ok to call the below for each app

```
@RequestMapping("/service-instances/{applicationName}")     public
 List<ServiceInstance> serviceInstancesByApplicationName(
```

How can I register automatically?

**EDIT**: More detailed question

(1) SERVICE App

> bootstrap - spring.application.name=pluralsight-toll-service

application props

```
server.port=0
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true

eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${random.int}
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

App

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class PluralsightEurekaTollrateServiceApplication {
```

I see app registered in eureka server

(2) Client
bootstrap

```
spring.application.name=pluralsight-tollrate-billboard
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
```

application.props

```
server.port=8081
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

App

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class PluralsightEurekaTollrateBillboardApplication {
```

Controller

```
   @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }
    
    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    @RequestMapping("/dashboard")
    public String GetTollRate(@RequestParam int stationId, Model m) {
        
        TollRate tr = restTemplate.getForObject("http://pluralsight-toll-service/tollrate/" + stationId, TollRate.class);
```

> Error: pluralsight-toll-service host is unknown

How can call service from client using the name

Comment: The registration against the registry can be done by adding @EnableDiscoveryClient on your Application class and by configuring the registry url and port in your properties. I am note sure this is all you're asking for. Could you please elaborate, if you're trying to do something more?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but didnt work.  I will  edit question

Comment: Ok, I think I get what you need to do now. Why don't use a feignclient, then? It supports service discovery out of the box

Comment: I take your point, but I would like to troubleshoot this issue. How can I know, if my client knows about services etc.

Comment: That use-case should work. In fact, we have a working sample that does just that: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-intro-demo/blob/main/user-service/src/main/java/org/example/userservice/UserServiceApplication.java#L118-L132. There might be an issue with the project setup - if you share it via GitHub link, I can take a look at it for you.

Comment: I tried with service name Upper case, didnt work.  Project on github  with linked repos https://github.com/users/kswat/projects/1

Comment: Have you checked that your app is registered in eureka?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue

Its all down to client project dependencies

```
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The names are too close
spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client is wrong
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client is the right one

Because of the wrong one, I had to add eureka-client of com.netflix.eureka. Cleaned all and it works
(Also I was missing spring-cloud , as I was creating from eclipse. In future will use initializ only )